# Redoing a hole on a entry way saddle

Tags: doors, hole, hardware

Our building entrance has a set of double doors, the door that is fixed is latched to the top frame and to the floor through a hole in a stone saddle.  The hole in the saddle is too big for that latch making the door not perfectly "fixed" (ie. it is loosely in place).

What material do you guys recommend could we use to fill the hole in the saddle (smaller than 1 inch in diameter) and then redo the hole?

Any suggestion/guidance will be welcome

Comment: How big is the hole and how big is the latch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put in a sleeve of brass or bronze?

1. Figure out exactly where the pin will hit and crfeate a template.
2. Get a piece of brass or bronze pipe whose indside diameter is a bit larger than the pin.
3. Drill out the stone to fit the outer diameter of the pipe.
4. Cut the pipe to a hair longer than the depth of the hole
5. Epoxy The pipe in
6. Gently file/emery the top edge to be flush with the stone.
7. Chamfer the inner edge of the pipe slightly to allow the pin to slide in easier.

You could use copper, but it is much softer and will wear sooner (and turn green sooner). Steel will rust unless you can find stainless steel pipe.

Comment: Perfect, I now have to find where to get scrap piping. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

A picture would help, but if I'm understanding correctly, many of those latches come with a metal plate:

[image]

Find/make one of those, and then screw it into the floor appropriately. Eg, if it's stone, you'll have to pre-drill a hole with a concrete bit, and install it using concrete screws (eg, tapcons).

Comment: Apologies for not having a picture to hand.  the latch is sort on the side of the door and the pin is inside the door.  There is no metal plate like the one on your picture.  I think our only option is to fill in the existing hole with some strong/durable material that won't break apart and redo a smaller hole.  What material could we use?

Comment: @macutan Even so, can you not get a metal plate underneath for it to go into?

Comment: the metal plate would have to be cut to size, I would imagine it would be easier to fill in the existing hole and re-drill (assuming that there is a type of fill-in concrete or other material that won't flake with time)...  below link to similar flush bolt we have. http://www.door.cc/assets/pics/about%20interior%20doors/Flush-bolt-.jpg

Comment: I was thinking hydraulic cement might work, but it sounds like you might be left with a very think piece of cement, which I'd be afraid would crumble easily. I'll let someone else add that answer that knows more about cement, minimum thickness and what pressure/strength to use. The metal plate would be more reliable and probably last as long as the door, and you could easily have it fabricated at a metal working shop.

Comment: yes, thank you Greg, I uppvoted your answer in hopes someone else will give me a solution without using the metal plate... I have a feeling I won't be able to screw in any screws without chipping the stone/marble looking saddle.

Comment: You should be able to epoxy the latch in place. There is an epoxy specifically made for anchoring hardware in concrete that should work well in this application.

Comment: @bcworkz you think the metallic plate would hold in place by "gluing" it to the saddle using epoxy?  I am afraid that with some of the use it will "unglued"

Comment: No, the plate version will not work at all, I put my comment in the wrong place. I meant you should epoxy the hardware that is loose in the hole, essentially a sleeve of epoxy instead of metal as in the answer you accepted.